# Difference between Batch and Sobject Collection composite resources

Tags: apex, composite

How are these two Composite API's different? From the documentation, with Batch, 25 unrelated subrequests can be passed into a single Batch Composite API and with Collections, it is 200.

Both the API's support GET, POST, PATCH and DELETE operations.

Given a use case of executing simple CRUD operations, anyone would go for Collection as Batch seems to be limiting(with only 25 subrequests). Any insights on how these both composite API's can be used to serve different purposes can be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### SObject Collections resource

Well, the *SObject Collections* resource is pretty much limited to basic CRUD. It can depend on a previous subrequest in the overall *composite* resource call (i.e. you could create an `Account`, and then reference that `Account` when you create a bunch of related `Contacts`), but it'd be harder to use a SObject Collections subrequest as a reference to another subrequest.

### Batch resource

The *Batch* composite resource can perform CRUD, but it isn't really suited to do *bulk* CRUD. Batch subrequests are completely independent (no way to reference the results of a previous subrequest). What *Batch* subrequests can do, however, is access things like chatter, flows, quick actions, invocable actions (i.e. Apex code), etc...

The ability to access those resources can make *Batch* composite requests really versatile. You could create an `Account` in one subrequest, then call an invocable method (passing some piece of information that allows you to find the `Account` you just created to an invocable variable) that goes on to create a bunch of related `Contacts`.

### Conclusion

While you can probably find some contrived way to make the abilities of each composite resource overlap to a degree, they all have things that they're better suited for.

- SObject Collections is great at creating large groups of records
- SObject Tree is great at creating shallow record hierarchies
- Batch is great at doing a sequence of more complex/varied tasks on a few, specific records (chatter, quick actions, updating field(s), invocable methods in Apex)